# photoshop or gimp color / light correction guidelines for a newbie

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, gimp

I would like to learn basic color / tone / light corrections for editing my car photos which are either over / low exposed; or blueish (due to heavy cloudy days)

For this purpose I can use either photoshop or gimp.. I will appreciate if you can provide quick, and easy guidelines (either step by step procedures or youtube videos)..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. This is quite a broad question for our site format,  you should [edit your question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/86490/edit) to narrow it down to what issue you're having with color correction. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Related question: [How do I fix this photo (poor quality/saturation/color) in Gimp](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27572/how-do-i-fix-this-photo-poor-quality-saturation-color-in-gimp)

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few YouTube links giving guidance on photoshop color correction:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1I9HcgAnHUw

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USi_ShbcM6o

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.